# how to delete table design from word document page using javascript ? Word js Add-in

Tags: javascript, azure, office365, add-in, word-addins

I am inserting a table design in word document last page from table html. how can I delete it
this is my code

```js
  async function NewMap() {
      try {
          await Word.run(async (context) => {  /*--html to word- https://stackoverflow.com/q/66576869  //-- word to html--- https://wordtohtml.net/   */
              var body = context.document.body;
              var paragraphs = body.paragraphs;
              context.load(paragraphs, 'length, last');
              await context.sync();

              const lastparagrsph = paragraphs.items[paragraphs.items.length - 1]
              // var selection = context.document.getSelection();
              var htmlContent = `<h4 style='margin-top:0in;margin-right:0in;margin-bottom:12.0pt;margin-left:0in;font-size:21px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;color:black;'>Map Title</h4>
       <div style = 'margin:0in;font-size:16px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;color:black;border:none;border-top:solid black 1.0pt;padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;margin-left:86.0pt;margin-right:0in;' >
       <p style='margin-top:12.0pt;margin-right:0in;margin-bottom:0in;margin-left:0in;text-align:right;text-indent:0in;border:none;padding:0in;font-size:16px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;color:black;font-style:italic;'>&nbsp;</p>
        </div >
      <table style="width: 100%;border: none;border-collapse:collapse;">
      <tbody>
      <tr>
      <td style="width: 0.68%;padding: 0in 5.4pt;vertical-align: top;">
          <h5 style='margin:0in;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;color:black;'>&nbsp;</h5>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 3.04%;padding: 0in 5.4pt;vertical-align: top;">
          <p style='margin:0in;font-size:16px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;color:black;'>&nbsp;</p>
      </td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
     </table>
     <p></p>
     <div style='margin:0in;font-size:16px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;color:black;border:none;border-top:solid black 1.0pt;padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;margin-left:86.0pt;margin-right:0in;'>
     <p style='margin-top:12.0pt;margin-right:0in;margin-bottom:0in;margin-left:0in;text-align:right;text-indent:0in;border:none;padding:0in;font-size:16px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;color:black;font-style:italic;'>&nbsp;</p>
     </div>
     <p><br></p>`;

              // selection.insertHtml(htmlContent, 'End');
              lastparagrsph.insertHtml(htmlContent, 'End');

              await context.sync();
          });

      } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
      }


  };
```

this method I am using for deleting

```js
 async function DeleteMap() {
     try {
         await Word.run(async (context) => {
             var body = context.document.body;
             var paragraphs = body.paragraphs;
             context.load(paragraphs, 'length, last');
             await context.sync();

             const lastParagraph = paragraphs.items[paragraphs.items.length - 1];
             const range = lastParagraph.getRange();

             // Delete the range to remove the inserted HTML content
             range.delete();

             await context.sync();
         });
     } catch (error) {
         console.log(error);
     }
 }
```

this is deleting if any text is on then end but not deleting my inserted html I want to delete my inserted htmlContent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using this my issue is solved

```js
async function NewMap() {
    try {
        await Word.run(async (context) => {
            const body = context.document.body;

            // Insert the custom structure within a content control with a specific tag
            const contentControl = body.insertContentControl();
            contentControl.tag = "customTableControl";
            contentControl.insertHtml(
                `
                <h4 style='margin-top:0in;margin-right:0in;margin-bottom:12.0pt;margin-left:0in;font-size:21px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;color:black;'>Map Title</h4>
                <div style='margin:0in;font-size:16px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;color:black;border:none;border-top:solid black 1.0pt;padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;margin-left:86.0pt;margin-right:0in;'>
                    <p style='margin-top:12.0pt;margin-right:0in;margin-bottom:0in;margin-left:0in;text-align:right;text-indent:0in;border:none;padding:0in;font-size:16px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;color:black;font-style:italic;'>&nbsp;</p>
                </div>
                <table style="width: 100%;border: none;border-collapse:collapse;">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width: 0.68%;padding: 0in 5.4pt;vertical-align: top;">
                                <h5 style='margin:0in;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;color:black;'>&nbsp;</h5>
                            </td>
                            <td style="width: 3.04%;padding: 0in 5.4pt;vertical-align: top;">
                                <p style='margin:0in;font-size:16px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;color:black;'>&nbsp;</p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <div style='margin:0in;font-size:16px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;color:black;border:none;border-top:solid black 1.0pt;padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;margin-left:86.0pt;margin-right:0in;'>
                    <p style='margin-top:12.0pt;margin-right:0in;margin-bottom:0in;margin-left:0in;text-align:right;text-indent:0in;border:none;padding:0in;font-size:16px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;color:black;font-style:italic;'>&nbsp;</p>
                </div>
               <p style='margin:0in;font-size:16px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;color:black;'>&nbsp;</p> `,
                Word.InsertLocation.replace
            );

            await context.sync();
        });


}catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
}

};
```

This is Delete Method

```js
async function DeleteMap() {
    try {
        await Word.run(async (context) => {
            const contentControlsWithTag = context.document.contentControls.getByTag('customTableControl');

            // Queue a command to load the content controls with the specified tag
            contentControlsWithTag.load('tag');

            // Synchronize the document state by executing the queued commands
            await context.sync();

            if (contentControlsWithTag.items.length === 0) {
                  console.log('No content control found.');
            } else {
                // Delete the content control
                contentControlsWithTag.items[0].delete();

                // Synchronize the document state by executing the queued command
                await context.sync();
                  console.log('Content control deleted.');
            }
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

I am adding content Control on inserting html then deleting it.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you have inserted multiple paragraphs with HTML content, including a table and other elements. To delete them, you should identify and delete each of these paragraphs.

Use the  `delete`  method of the  `Range`  object to remove the inserted HTML content. Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32777440/how-to-delete-a-created-table-using-javascript).

- Add a unique identifier (e.g., a specific HTML comment or a placeholder) around the HTML content you want to delete. Then, you can search for that identifier within the last paragraph and remove the content accordingly.

```js
var htmlContent = `<h4 style='margin-top:0in;margin-right:0in;margin-bottom:12.0pt;margin-left:0in;font-size:21px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;color:black;'>Map Title</h4>
<!-- StartMyCustomContent -->
<div style='margin:0in;font-size:16px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;color:black;border:none;border-top:solid black 1.0pt;padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;margin-left:86.0pt;margin-right:0in;'>
   <p style='margin-top:12.0pt;margin-right:0in;margin-bottom:0in;margin-left:0in;text-align:right;text-indent:0in;border:none;padding:0in;font-size:16px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;color:black;font-style:italic;'>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
<table style="width: 100%;border: none;border-collapse:collapse;">
   <!-- Some table content here -->
</table>
<p></p>
<div style='margin:0in;font-size:16px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;color:black;border:none;border-top:solid black 1.0pt;padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;margin-left:86.0pt;margin-right:0in;'>
   <p style='margin-top:12.0pt;margin-right:0in;margin-bottom:0in;margin-left:0in;text-align:right;text-indent:0in;border:none;padding:0in;font-size:16px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;color:black;font-style:italic;'>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
<p><br></p>
<!-- EndMyCustomContent -->`;
```

- Modify your `DeleteMap` function to search for and delete the content between the custom comment tags.

```
async function DeleteMap() {
    try {
        await Word.run(async (context) => {
            var body = context.document.body;
            var paragraphs = body.paragraphs;
            context.load(paragraphs, 'length, last');
            await context.sync();

            const lastParagraph = paragraphs.items[paragraphs.items.length - 1];

            // Retrieve the HTML content as a string
            const paragraphHtml = lastParagraph.getHtml();

            // Find the custom comment tags
            const startTag = '<!-- StartMyCustomContent -->';
            const endTag = '<!-- EndMyCustomContent -->';

            // Check if the custom tags are present
            if (paragraphHtml.indexOf(startTag) !== -1 && paragraphHtml.indexOf(endTag) !== -1) {
                // Remove the content between the custom tags
                const startIndex = paragraphHtml.indexOf(startTag);
                const endIndex = paragraphHtml.indexOf(endTag) + endTag.length;
                const newHtmlContent = paragraphHtml.substring(0, startIndex) + paragraphHtml.substring(endIndex);
                lastParagraph.insertHtml(newHtmlContent, Word.InsertLocation.replace);
            }

            await context.sync();
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```